# How to call axios.get inside a camponent, async on the component function thows error

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am trying to put my first React Native app together. I am trying some random stuff. I believe it's the first time I call axios.get. I used some posts http requests using axios and they went fine. But I cannot display data from the api. My component is as follows.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { colors } from './utils/colors';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
//import { styled } from 'styled-components'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import axios from 'axios'

let i = 0;

export const PedidosCorrida = async () => { // ATENTION ASYNC IS THE MAIN CAUSE OF MY ERROR RIGHT NOW

    let dados = [];


    await axios
        .get("http://192.168.0.57:3000/corridas"

        )
        .then((response) => {

            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                dados.push(
                    <View>
                        <Text>{i}  <Button title='fazer corrida'>    {' '}  </Button></Text>

                        <View>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                )
            }
        }
        )

    return (
        <>
            {dados}
        </>
    )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {

    },
    text: {
        color: colors.branco
    }
})
```

This component queries an API and get some data. As I said I am learning I tossed some code but I really expected it to work. I know that I am not displaying the api's data in the component above. But the api is not even being called because of the error.

I use the component like this.

```
export const Procurar = () => {

    return (

        <>
            </View>

               <PedidosCorrida>

               </PedidosCorrida>
   


                  <View>
               </>
      )
 }
```

The erro I am getting is this: ERROR  Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

If I remove the async from the component I get no error but is like the loop is not called "dados" is empty.

Comment: Storing elements in state in not recommended in React. You can just store the data and map over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX components cannot be `async`. Also, you need a state variable tracked via `useState` so that a re-render can be triggered when your data is fetched. Finally, you have to move your `axios` call into a `useEffect` hook, so it's not called on every re-render, which might cause an infinite loop.

You component will then look like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const PedidosCorrida = () => { 
    let [dados, setDados] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      await axios
        .get("http://192.168.0.57:3000/corridas")
        .then((response) => {
            const newDados = []

            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                newDados.push(
                    <View>
                        <Text>
                          {i}  
                          <Button title='fazer corrida'>    
                            {' '}  
                          </Button>
                        </Text>
                    <View>
               )
           }
           
           setDados([...dados, ...newDados])
       })
       
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {dados}
        </>
    )
}
```